# Text field Type value is not visible to user in Ext js form field

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

i am new to Ext js. i have creted a field set inside a form which has two text fields. when i type any words inside of text field then it is not proprely visible to user. please help out in this with sample codes.....

Comment: post here whatever you tried.

Comment: i have created textfield in a form...when typed any text into that field it is not properly visible what i have typed , because it is small how to change the size of textarea...

Comment: but if you post your code..then people can see and modify it.

Comment: Yes, please post your code. We can't tell why the textfield is too small without seeing your code.

Comment: This i gave length for Text field very lesser value thats y it happened.